# If a function is continuous at $x_0$, then it must be defined on a neighborhood of $x_0$?

Tags: calculus, continuity

The title is all my question. Let me state it again:

> If a function is continuous and defined at $x_0$, then it must be defined on a neighborhood of $x_0$?

It seems trivial, but I cannot prove it. Here is my thought: suppose the contrary, for every $n$, there exists $x_n$ such that $|x_n-x_0|<\frac{1}{n}$ but $f$ is not defined at $x_n$. Thus $(x_n)\rightarrow x_0$, so $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x_0)$, but $f(x_n)$ is not defined at all. Of course the solution in not correct, since $(x_n)$ must be taken from the domain of $f$. However, the hypothesis does not mention the domain at all.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Ok, the definitions of continuity, although equivalent, are highly dependent on context (which you haven't stated clearly). At any rate, the definition of continuity at a point usually requires that the function be defined on a neighborhood of this point (otherwise it makes little sense).

Comment: No. $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is continuous at $x=0$ but is not defined on a neighourhood of $0$ (in the usual Euclidean sense).

Comment: Every function is continuous at any isolated point of its domain by definition, because you must choose the convergent sequence $x_n$ from its domain.

Comment: @mfl: You have a point, but then we usually say that $f$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$, and $[0,\epsilon)$ is a neighborhood of $0$ in the *relative topology* on $[0,\infty)$. That's why I said that the question is missing some context (what does he mean by neighborhood?).

Comment: @PedroM. You are right. In this question the context is very important to give an answer.

Comment: @PedroM.I don't know if there is another definition for neighborhood, but what I mean in the problem above is $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon )$ as usual.

Comment: @TienKhaPham Then mfl provided a counterexample (see his comment).